# K&R 1.5.4, can anyone explain the else if in this code example?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, state-management

I am painfully making my way through K&R 2nd ed. and I am not clear on what the final if (else if) is doing in example 1.5.4.

```
include stdio.h

define IN  1

define OUT 0

main()

{

        int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

        state = OUT;
        nl = nw = nc = 0;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
            ++nc;
            if (c == '\n')
                ++nl;
            if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
                state = OUT;

            else if (state == OUT) {
                state = IN;
                ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

Does it mean: if state is OUT, then change state to IN, +1 to nw in any case

or

if state is OUT, do nothing, otherwise change state to IN, +1 to nw if state is IN

Comment in the text is: '[...] the [statement] after the **else** is an **if** that controls two statements in braces.'

For some reason I am having a hard time getting what is happening there.  Can anyone help? I get a brain freeze every time I look at this.

Comment: Neither. You should refresh your knowledge about the `if-else` construct.

Comment: It's possible the placement of the blank line is causing confusion --- the first `if` is one thing, and the second `if` and the `else if` are a different thing.

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site!  Check out the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52336172/edit) to include more information, for example, if commenters ask.

Comment: It's a little state-machine that counts words and newlines. Just from that, you should be able to work out what is going on.

Comment: thx for the quick help.  This is the first mention of else if, and I am trying to be sure my understanding is correct before moving on.  I can see it is saying that if state is not OUT it will be IN, but how does ++nw happen? It should only happen if state goes back to IN after being OUT, yes?

Comment: @deeprealms, BTW, `else if` is not a standalone construct, it's just an `if` clause inside an `else` clause, like this: `if (...) {hey();} else {if (...) {wow();}}`

Comment: It looks like the right curly braces are not lined up correctly in your question. If you look at the book you will see that the } on the line after ++nw; lines up with the else if. That is a clue that everything between the curly braces runs together if state == OUT.

Comment: @Bobby Durrett, thx, everything lines up in my IDE, but your comment makes it more clear to me...so if OUT, switch back to IN (ready to be triggered again by a blank for next getchar), and increment 1.  If not out, this else  block gets skipped, so no increment, and state is still set to be triggered as before.  If that makes any sense :0)

Comment: Sounds like you have it.

Comment: @ForceBru Here goes my attempt to be a good corporate citizen in view of the [new C of C](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) :) .  I submit for your consideration that "you should refresh your knowledge" is inopportune in response to a question specifically soliciting that knowledge.  The OP appears to me to be genuinely trying to understand and having difficulty, and I think this question is a reasonable one.  How does that strike you?

Comment: @cxw, the discussion of the if-else construct is right after this example code, on the next page. So... the answer is _right there_. I don't have anything against the OP posting here, and my comment means just what it says: I wasn't trying to be sarcastic or anything like that. Just read the next few pages, and everything should be clear!

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks for the additional information.  I don't have the book, so I didn't know that :) .  (I think I used to have it, but my bookshelf overflowed :( )

Comment: @ForceBru, I see the explanation,  which I quoted in part above.  I guess I needed to sleep on it, cause I read it today and realized I misinterpreted statement 1 and 2 to refer to parts in else if block. Actually, I guess this example has 3 statements, but the explanation only refered to 2, so I got confused. 
 Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you encounter any of these: `space` or `tab` or `newline` then it sets your position/state to `OUT` which is indicative that you are currently not in midst of some text (example `asd673r23@#$#`) and it means you have just found another word in the string, hence it incrementing the total no. of words by 1.

Comment: Thx very much for your answer.  I can see that OUT means ++nw, I guess IN means no increment in nw, so that statement is ignored if state is IN, but the way it is written makes is seem like it would apply in any case.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me crazy and nobodies answer provided what I needed.. but did guide me! Here's the confusing part for newbies.
These two states == out should be viewed somewhat independently.

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
                state = OUT;

            else if (state == OUT) {
                state = IN;
                ++nw;
```

The first state = out sets the state to out. Whereas the second else if starts with the state == out as the out being 0 as previously initialized. The state = out from the first part doesn't carry over to the else if statement. The else if occurs instead of. Hope this helps someone and do correct me if I'm wrong.